# Explain a transpiration graph

Tags: homework, plant-physiology

[image]

The solution is A, but I think both A and C are correct. For choice C, stomata that protected by hairs will have a greater amount of water vapour around them, hence lower water potential gradient. Hence, this results in the reduction in the rate of transpiration, as well as choice A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I don't come across graphs like these too often, I guess the answer should be A because...

From the graph, it is clear that **Leaf 1** has more mass than **Leaf 2** after 5 hours. This means there is a lower rate of transpiration in Leaf 1, which can definitely be explained by a thicker cuticle (since the thicker the cuticle, less is the water lost). Hence **choice A** is **correct**.

Now, look at choice C. Like you said, in leaves where stomata are protected by hairs, there will be lower rate of transpiration. Then, obviously **Leaf 2** should have a higher mass than **Leaf 1**, right? But this is not the case (as per the graph). Hence, **choice C** is **incorrect**.